# The function of sum() in python

Tags: python, probability-distribution

I am reading some code with python, which is about probability distribution. But in many cases, instead of using a framework like PyTorch to compute distribution, it uses the following code

```
def sample_energy_0(self, y, M):
    device = next(self.parameters()).device
    x = torch.randn(M, y.shape[0], self.latent_dim).to(device)
    return x

def energy_0(self, x, y):
    return (x**2).sum(axis=2, keepdims=True) / 2
```

How does the function `sum(axis=2)` work here?

Comment: This IS using PyTorch. Don't you see `torch.randn()`?

Comment: Or maybe it's using numpy. Either way, `x` is a numpy array, and it has a `sum()` method that calculates the sum of that axis of the array.

Answer (score 1):

`x.sum(axis=2)` means for a tensor of shape `(A, B, C, ...)`, the elements along the `C` dimension are summed to yield a new tensor of shape `(A, B, ...)`. `keepdims=True` means that the `C` dimension is "kept" as a dummy dimension of `1`:

```py
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.arange(0, 30).reshape(2,3,5)
>>> x
tensor([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
         [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
         [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

        [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
         [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
         [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])
>>> x.shape
torch.Size([2, 3, 5])
>>> x.sum(axis=2).shape
torch.Size([2, 3])
>>> x.sum(axis=2, keepdims=True).shape
torch.Size([2, 3, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression `(x**2).sum(axis=2, keepdims=True) / 2` isn't calling the function `sum()`, it's calling a method named `.sum()` on some object.

The type of the object is unknown from looking at your code alone, but it seems likely that `x` is expected to be a `Tensor`, which has a `.sum()` method, which you can find in [the documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.sum.html#torch.Tensor.sum). However, since a keyword parameter called `axis` is passed, it's also quite possible the function expects a numpy array, and it is calling the [`numpy.sum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html).

The `(x**2)` applies the `**` (raising to a power) operation on `x` and `2` and the result is typically the same type as a type of `x`. So, the `.sum()` method can be called on the result.

Note that you could call `energy_0()` with `x` being either a `Tensor` or a `numpy` array and it would work just fine, as long as the code in the function is compatible with the interface of the class of the object being passed.